# Javascript array undefined in for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, undefined

I have a problem with a javascript array: "arrFinal[i] is undefined"

In my script arrFinal is dynamically generated

```
function fillTextareas () {
var arrFinal = [];
arrFinal[0] = [];

....
....
// Then some code that define the content of arrFinal, the length of arrFinal ( tailleArrFinal, tailleArrSubFinal)
....
....


for(i=0;i<=tailleArrFinal;i++){
        for(j=0;j<tailleArrSubFinal;j++) {
            $("form textarea#t" + i + "_" + j).val(arrFinal[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

When the function is called, a dump show me that the array arrFinal is correctly fill and the script works but i have an alert "arrFinal[i] is undefined". How can i do that without alert ?
Thanks !!

Comment: Where is that alert you are calling... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like an off-by-one error in the outer loop.

It should be `i < tailleArrFinal`, not `<=`.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your loop I can see at least 2 errors: you miss "**var**" and "**.length**" (you have to test for array length!)

try to replace:

```
for(i=0;i<=tailleArrFinal;i++){
        for(j=0;j<tailleArrSubFinal;j++) {
            $("form textarea#t" + i + "_" + j).val(arrFinal[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

with:

```
for(var i=0;i<tailleArrFinal.length;i++){
        for(var j=0; j<tailleArrSubFinal.length; j++) {
            $("form textarea#t" + i + "_" + j).val(arrFinal[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```