# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string-matching

I am trying to convert two strings to same format like toUpperCase/toLowerCase to compare two strings regardless of case sensitive in javaScript. Below is my function.

```
    function submitForm() {

    var usernames=['one','two','Test'];
    var cpusername = "test";
            var flag = 0;

   if (cpusername !== "")
                {
    for (var k = 0; k < usernames.length; k++)
                {
        var upperCasecpusername=cpusername.toUpperCase();
        var getusername= usernames[k];
        var upperCaseusername=getusername.toUpperCase();

                    if (upperCasecpusername === upperCaseusername)
                    {
                        flag=1;
     console.log(flag);
            //document.getElementById('cpusername').value = '';
                $.messager.alert("Message", "Someone already has username"+cpusername+". Try another!!", '');                    


                    }
                }
                }
```

am getting this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined .I have also tried to convert toString() first and then to toLowercase() .It was also erred (toString() undefined). Also suggest me if any other ways to compare two string regardless of case sensitive. Thanks!

Comment: Your if condition `k <= usernames.length;` will make it go past the array bounds. Array's are 0 indexed so the last index of an array will be Array `length-1`

Comment: where is `toUpperCase` in your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript array undefined in for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571451/javascript-array-undefined-in-for-loop)

Comment: @PatrickEvans I have modified code. still facing same issue

Comment: Your code works fine with the edit, no errors are thrown. [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4f3rmdk2/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var getusername= ""+usernames[k];
```

If that doesn't work, then this could be the problem:

Switch

```
for (var k = 0; k <= usernames.length; k++)
```

for

```
for (var k = 0; k <= usernames.length-1; k++)
```

Comment: Thanks man. It does worked. but why toUpperCase is not working for arrays. any idea?

Comment: Or even `for (var k = 0; k < usernames.length; k++)`.

Comment: Did you try my first suggestion? that should make `.toUpperCase` work. If not, then I really don't know what the error could be.

Comment: @EthanJCRubik yes your first suggestion worked fine. That made uppercase to work. my question is why it doesnot directly converting to uppercase like java.

Comment: Don't use the first suggestion as it will convert `undefined` values to the string `"undefined"`, and while it will stop the errors from being thrown it will give the false impression that you are looping over your array correctly when using `<= usernames.length`

Answer (score 1):

Try This

**js code**

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

    var usernames=['one','two','Test'];
    var cpusername = "test";
            var flag = 0;

   if (cpusername !== "")
                {
    for (var k = 0; k < usernames.length; k++)
     {
        var upperCasecpusername=cpusername.toLowerCase();
        var getusername= usernames[k];
        console.log(getusername);
        var upperCaseusername=getusername.toLowerCase();

            if (upperCasecpusername === upperCaseusername)
           {
                    console.log(upperCasecpusername);
                    console.log(upperCaseusername);
                        flag=1;
                     console.log(flag);
            //document.getElementById('cpusername').value = '';
                alert( "Someone already has username"+cpusername+". Try another!!", '');                    


             }
       }
    }
});
```

You can view [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/tenigada/s3nyp4df/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Using functions `.toLowerCase()` & `.toUpperCase()` are fine, but as requested to other way to string case insensitive comparison, I would recommend to use `regex`.
Try something like this for case insensitive string comparison

```
var str= "TEST";
var result = str.match(/test/i);
if(result){
// Write logic once the match found
}
```