# I can't make input textbox in upper case using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am making a program wherein all textboxes are converted into UPPERCASE through CSS. In my Javascript, I want to pass it to server with the same values as UPPERCASE, too. However, I encountered an error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined"

I already tried different solutions from different users of StackOverFlow such as [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35643980/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-touppercase-of-undefined) but still error.

Here's my code:

```
  // put all gathered data in an array variable so as to send to the server for saving          
  var param = new Array();
  param[0] = clientType;
  param[1] = catv_provider;
  param[2] = existing_subs;
  param[3] = gender;
  param[4] = lastname;
  param[5] = firstname;
  param[6] = midname;
  var param2 = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < param.length; i++) {
    param2[i] = param[i].toUpperCase();
  }
```

Comment: One of the values in the array is empty/undefined. I'd suggest using `console.log` in the loop to find out which. Also, there's no need to create a new array for the uppercase'd values.

Comment: Also please when you create a snippet, add relevant HTML and remove irrelevant code in a [mcve]

Comment: Consider putting all the IDs in an array and then looping over that (using `map`) to get their values, and then converting them to uppercase.

Comment: Most probably is one of the value is `null` or different type than string, because I saw potential `non-string value` such as `preffered_date`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are getting value `undefined`.

You can modify your loop as

```
    for (var i = 0; i < param.length; i++) {
     if(typeof(param[i])!=="undefined") { //skipping undefined
        param2[i] = param[i].toUpperCase();
     }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you. This really makes sense. It solved my problem. thanks!

Comment: @CristyNazareno, Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try Following

```
   for (var i = 0; i < param.length; i++) {
        if(param[i] != null){    
        param[i].toUpperCase();
     }
    }
```