# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toUpperCase')

Tags: javascript, typeerror, uppercase

I have been trying to convert the text input to proper case and sentence case. Proper case seems to work fine but the sentence case throws
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toUpperCase')`. Went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35643980/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-touppercase-of-undefined) post and applied few changes but found no luck. Surprisingly, the `.toUpperCase()` works just fine in the proper case function.

```js
document.getElementById("proper-case").addEventListener("click", function() {
  let words = document.querySelector("textarea").value.split(" ");
  let string = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    string += words[i][0].toUpperCase() + words[i].substring(1).toLowerCase();
    if (i != words.length - 1) {
      string += " ";
    }
  }
  document.querySelector("textarea").value = string;
});


document.getElementById("sentence-case").addEventListener("click", function() {
  let sentences = document.querySelector("textarea").value.split(".");
  let string = "";
  console.log(sentences);
  for (let i = 0; i <= sentences.length - 1; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
      string += sentences[i][0].toUpperCase() + sentences[i].substring(1).toLowerCase() + ".";
    } else {
      string += " " + sentences[i][1].toUpperCase() + sentences[i].substring(2).toLowerCase() + ".";
    }
  }
  console.log(string)
  document.querySelector("textarea").value = string;
})
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>

<button id="proper-case">Proper Case</button>
<button id="sentence-case">Sentence Case</button>
```

Can someone please tell me what the problem here is?

Comment: What value are you typing into the text field? Exactly which line is throwing the error?

Comment: @Phil Just random bunch of sentences separated with periods. Turns out the split(".") leaves an empty string at the end which needed to dealt with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .split('.') operation returns an empty string at its last array item, therefore, `sentences[i][1]` is undefined. To solve this, you can check if sentences[i] is not an empty string.

In addition, you can use String.trimLeft() on the else case.

Answer (score 1):

This line causes the error.

`string += " " + sentences[i][1].toUpperCase() + sentences[i].substring(2).toLowerCase() + ".";`

your split separates the string at a point. if there is nothing after the point, there is also an empty element in the array. and that is why the [0] throws an error. because a lerrer string has no first character. to fix the error, you must first catch this case.

**for example**

```
document.getElementById("sentence-case").addEventListener("click", function() {
  let sentences = document.querySelector("textarea").value.split(".");
  let string = "";
  console.log('=>', sentences);
  for (let i = 0; i <= sentences.length - 1; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
      string += sentences[i][0].toUpperCase() + sentences[i].substring(1).toLowerCase() + ".";
    } else {
      console.log(sentences[i][1]);
      let s1 = ''      
      let s3 = ''      
      if(typeof sentences[i][0] !== "undefined") {        
        s1 = " " + sentences[i][0].toUpperCase();
        s3 = ".";
      } 
      string += s1 + sentences[i].substring(2).toLowerCase() + s3;
    }
  }
  console.log(string)
  document.querySelector("textarea").value = string;
})
```