# Google Script array value undefined

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

i wrote a code that should take a value from a cell and than convert it to the string and than into the array. its working fine. I can see the value of `arr` in Logs as an array with the input of the cell. For example, in the cell are " dog, cat " and tha `arr` value in Logs is [dog, cat].

But after i create this array, i would like to make a loop on it. And than i become in Logs, that `arr` is undefined. Can somebody help me please? im working on it for 2 days :(

Here is my code:

```
function animal (s,z){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var range = sheet.getRange("SM");
var columnNumber = getColumnNumberOfSM(s);
var rowNumber = getRowNumberOfSM(z);
var colAction = columnNumber + 1;
var action = sheet.getRange(rowNumber, colAction, 1, 1).getValues();
var bar = action.toString();
var arr = [{}];
arr = bar.split(", ");
//return arr; // returns an array [dog, cat]
var foo = arr; // underfined
for (var i = 0; i <= foo.length; ++i) {
if (foo[i] == "dog") {
     Logger.log(upload());
  }
 }
}
```

now i edit my code and its working fine,but only with "dog" but not with "cat"

```
function animal(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var action = sheet.getRange("C3").getValue();
var bar = action.toString();
var arr = bar.split(", ");
for (var i = 0; i <= arr.length; ++i) {
if (arr[i] == "dog") { // works
     Logger.log(upload());
  }
if (arr[i] == "cat") { // doesn't work
     Logger.log(upload());
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Just as with your previous question on this same topic, you are accessing an undefined index when you iterate your array `foo`:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571451/javascript-array-undefined-in-for-loop
Your question and title do not match - you are not returning anything. Please edit your question to **[clearly state your issue and your research into the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**
Consider also logging the value of each array element as you iterate, i.e. `Logger.log(arr[i]); if (arr[i] == ...)`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to initiate arr as blank you can directly initialize it as a result to split method , also one point I didn't get is why do you need to assign arr to foo? You can directly iterate through arr.length and perform the required operation.

Here's my working snippet.

```
var parts = path.split(",");
  for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    if (parts[i] == 'dog'){ 
        Logger.log(parts[i]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: thank you a lot for you quick answer.I edit my function as you said, but its working only with the first name in it ("dog"), but not with ("cat"). Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide excel sheet value sample to check further. Also this issue seems to be more specific with Javascript.